# Any chances to bring a "long-ago-deleted question" back?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions

A long time ago, I had a problem with writing DVD +R/-R DL discs on my desktop computer, and I asked a question on SU. Then I deleted that question after some time since I couldn't find a solution.

I just wonder, is it possible to bring back a deleted question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question undeleted:

[Double Layer DVDR Burning Problem](https://superuser.com/questions/93168/double-layer-dvdr-burning-problem-i-o-error)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to "undelete" a question by casting votes to undelete it. The exact number depends on the number of answers and age I believe. I *think* the minimum is 3 votes.

Comment: OK but how can I see the deleted question? It is "deleted".

Comment: @Mehper: 10k users and moderators should be able to view deleted questions.

Comment: I can only see "recently deleted posts". I am after a specific question of mine, and it was looong long time ago when I asked it.